# how can i make an anchor tag to follow a link (href) and then make a click programatically on that link.

Tags: jquery

I am completely new to jquery and is it possible to make an anchor tag follow the href page and then produce a click event automatically on an element.(nextpageanchor)

for eg:

//Current page

`<a href="nextpage.html" id="currentpageanchor">`Click to go to nextpage`</a>`   //on clicking manually v go to nextpg

//next page

`<a href="#" id="nextpageanchor">`I do some logic make me click programatically`</a>`

please help

Comment: I don't really what you're trying to ask. Are you looking for in-page linking like `somepage.html#achor`?

Comment: Not sure if I get you right but you can use `.click`: http://api.jquery.com/click/ to trigger a click event. Be aware that almost all browsers I know will block this kind of "fake redirection" for security purposes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your current page you could add a parameter to your url like

```
<a href ="nextpage.html?cameFromA=true"></a>
```

And on your nextpage: you could look if the parameter is available and use `$('something').trigger('click');`

Comment: Hi EvilP the code works totally fine for other pages to make a click on this page, But on the same page this triggering does'nt work. Can you suggest me some thing on this.?? I have used the command as follows 'var url=document.URL.split('#')[1];  $("."+url).trigger('click'); ' But it doesnt work on the same page :(

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have an anchor link like so:

```
<a name="my_anchor" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
```

That's on another page; the link from the original would be something like:

```
<a href="another_page.html#my_anchor">Link to anchor on another page</a>
```

Then, to make the function run, a simple `test()` should work:

```
$(function(){
    if(/#my_anchor/i.test(window.location.hash)) {
        $('a[name="my_anchor"]').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean...but if this is what you want:

Click #nextpageanchor and go to the link in #currentpageanchor, this should do it.

```
$('#nextpageanchor').on('click',function () {
    $('#currentpageanchor').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you cannot control the jquery event in the page that will be loaded when that anchor is followed directly.
What you could do is like EvilP said, pass some flag to the server when the anchor is clicked, and when you render the other page, check for flag and if the flag is set then echo out some javascript triggering a click event on the page onload.